# Security of a GAS

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet containing data feeding a Google Maps website. The spreadsheet is filled through a form where the user has to specify an address. A Google Apps Script is triggered when a record is added to the spreadsheet. The script runs a Google Maps geocoding service to get the coordinates. For now I use a free account of the service. I would like to use a Google Maps for Work account to increase my quotas. It requires to generate a signature (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth?hl=fr) from a crypto key. This key has to stay private. The GAS langage is based on JavaScript but seems to process server-side. I am a little confused about some security concerns.

How secure is a GAS? Is there any security concern to provide such an important information in a GAS?

Best regards,
Damien

Answer (score 3):

Since the script is stored and executed server-side under the permissions of your Google account, it is as secure as any other Google document. That is, one will only be able to see it if you share your script (or if it's contained, share the container document, e.g. a spreadsheet).

I'd say it's pretty secure. And is only breakable if someone hacks into Google servers or, which is more likely, hack into your account by some mistake on your part: stolen phone, phishing scam, accidentally Drive share, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Apps Script is served over HTTPS.  "S" on the end.  As opposed to HTTP.  No "S" on the end.  All the transmissions are encrypted. Your account is only as secure as your password and log in procedure.  But that's true for everything with a password.  Google does have a two step verification process if you want to be extra secure.

[Google Documentation - Two Step](http://www.google.com/landing/2step/?utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk&utm_medium=ha)